# how do I disable "Allow your PC to be discoverable by other PCs and devices" blade

Tags: windows, windows-10, sysprep

This [posters issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/autoamtically-disable-allow-your-pc-to-be/d9d0b094-6e52-412f-a007-4d96be4d7084?rtAction=1496934524482) is a good description of the issue I want to address.

I'm building an image based on Windows 10 Enterprise IOT. When the devices with this image are built in the factory they show the 'make pc discoverable' blade. when they first boot to the shell. I never want to show this. I don't care if the units are discoverable or not, I want to either pre-set the option for any and all networks or just hide the side blade.

I have complete control of the build and answer file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Roll out group policy for your domain that blocks it. If no domain, setup a limited user account and an administrator account and use that admin account to turn it off. The limited user can't turn it on without admin rights, which they don't have.

Comment: but how can I "turn it off"? This is the problem, there is no clear way to disable it.